# Eclipse SVN history - go back to last month

Tags: eclipse, svn

When I open the history view for SVN in Eclipse, I can go back one week. I would like to go back further, one month, or even back to the first revision years ago. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

```
svn log
```

Shows you broad information: log messages attached to revisions, and which paths changed in each revision.